# Using bracket notation on a JavaScript number

Tags: javascript, indexing, prototype

I was reading through code submitted by someone on a coding forum. I came across something like `100[0]` in his code. I expected JavaScript to throw an error but to my surprise it is `undefined`. I have known the bracket notation to be used with objects, arrays and strings but it is quite strange that it doesn't throw when used with a number.

Is this similar to invoking a method on a string literal like `"FOO".toLowerCase()` where the string is first coerced to an object and then `toLowerCase` is invoked? Can someone explain to me what is going on here?

Comment: it is just a standard behaviour of a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors). this works on any type.

Comment: Yes, it's the same as your string literal example. Try, for example `100["toExponential"]()`. However, the code `100[0]` doesn't really make sense - you can't get numeric properties off numbers. Unless perhaps `Number.prototype` was altered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While numbers like `12` are primitives in javascript, you can still access properties on it. Take a look at the [Number API Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) for what kinds of properties a number has.

For example, `(2).toString()` will yield `'2'`. So will `2['toString']()`. This should hopefully help explain why such syntax is still valid.

What makes this possible is a technique called "boxing". Most of the time when working with numbers, we aren't accessing properties or methods on the number, so the runtime will just use primitive values to keep things quick. But, the moment we try to access a property like toString() on the number, then a temporary instance will automatically be created for that number so that you can access the property.

This is mostly an invisible process, but artifacts of it are noticeable in the language. For example, comparing two primitives, `2 === 2`, is true. But if we force boxing to happen with the Number constructor, `new Number(2) === new Number(2)`, then we'll be comparing two number object, and these objects follow the same rules as any other objects, so this will actually evaluate to false. (Note that we can only observe these kinds of behaviors by force creating the number instances, the auto-boxing will never happen for anything but equality checks).